# What do $n$ and $k$ refer to when we have a function symbol $f^n_k$?

Tags: functions, logic, notation

**What do $n$ and $k$ refer to when we have a function symbol $f^n_k$?**

From what I undesrtand, $n$ is the arity of the function, for example we can write the product function $a * b$ as $f^2_1 a b$

I remember my teacher saying something about $k$ being "k many functions". What does this mean?

Comment: It's not clear what the context is (what course is this? which textbook?), but it sounds like $k$ is the number of outputs of $f$.  Multiplication operator takes 2 values and produces 1.

Comment: See Hamilton, page 50-52.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the context is a presentation of first-order predicate calculus. In that case, $k$ is just a number that uniquely identifies $f^n_k$ among the various function symbols of arity $n$ in the theory of interest. So in the theory of a ring, you would have two binary operators (addition and multiplication) and you might choose to use $f^2_1$ for addition and $f^2_2$ for multiplication.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Am I allowed to define the operators myself? For instance, can I simply define $f_2^3$ for the power function?

Comment: If you are doing first-order predicate calculus, then yes it is up to you to decide what axioms you are using for the various function symbols. (However does your power function have arity $3$?)

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I meant to say $f^2_3$ . Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

That notation shows up in many contexts with different meaning.

From the little bit of context you display it could indeed be
$$
f_k^n : A^n \to B
$$
As you can evaluate a function of $n$ arguments in $n$-steps, using [Schönfinkel/Frege/Curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) you can associate it with $n$ functions of a single argument each.